# Is there a definitive JavaScript (not jQuery) method for checking whether or not a web page has loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, load

Is there a definitive JavaScript method for checking whether or not a web page has loaded completely? Completely, meaning 100% complete. HTML, scripts, CSS, images, plugins, AJAX, everything!

As user interaction can effect AJAX, let's assume there is no further user interaction with the page, apart from the initial page request.

Comment: "completely" meaning what exactly? Just the DOM, or also Images, CSS style sheets...?

Comment: Completely, meaning 100% complete. HTML, scripts, CSS, images, plugins, everything!

Comment: Would like a standard JavaScript non-jQuery solution.

Comment: I like a solution that will work for pages that I do not control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for is pretty much impossible. There is no way to determine whether everything has loaded *completely*. Here's why:

- On a lot of webpages, AJAX only starts once the `onload` (or `DOMReady`) event fires, making the method of using the `onload` event to see if the page has loaded impossible.
- You could theoretically tell if the webpage was performing an AJAX request by overriding `window.XMLHttpRequest`, but you still couldn't tell if plugins like Flash were still loading or not.
- On some sites, like [Twitter.com](http://twitter.com), the page only loads once and simply makes AJAX requests to the server every time the user clicks a link. How do you tell if the page has finished loading on a page like that?
- In fact, the browser itself can't be completely certain whether the page has completely finished loading, or whether it's about to make more AJAX requests.

The only way to know for sure that everything loaded is to have *every single piece* of code on the page that loads something tell your code that it has finished once it loads.

---

A hacky, incomplete solution: You could try overriding `XMLHttpRequest` with a function that wraps the existing `XMLHttpRequest` and returns it. That would allow you to tell if a AJAX event is currently taking place. However, that solution wouldn't work for seeing if plugins are loaded, and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between AJAX events that are triggered at page load and AJAX requests that happen periodically, like the ones on Stack Overflow that change the Stack Exchange icon on the top-left if you have new notifications.

Try something like this:

```
(function(oldHttpRequest){
  // This isn't cross-browser, just a demonstration
  // of replacing XMLHttpRequest

  // Keep track of requests
  var requests_running = 0;

  // Override XMLHttpRequest's constructor
  window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    // Create an XMLHttpRequest
    var request = new oldHttpRequest();

    // Override the send method
    var old_send = request.send;
    request.send = function () {
      requests_running += 1;
      old_send.apply(request, arguments);
    };

    // Wait for it to load
    req.addEventListener("load", function() {
      requests_running -= 1;
    }, false);

    // Return our modified XMLHttpRequest
    return request;
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Check every 50 ms to see if no requests are running
    setTimeout(function checkLoad() {
      if(requests_running === 0)
      {
        // Load is probably complete
      }
      else
        setTimeout(checkLoad, 50);
    }, 50);
  }, false);
})(window.XMLHttpRequest)
```

Comment: Can we assumer there is no further user interaction after the initial page request? Still impossible?

Comment: @trnsfrmr It's not possible to be _completely_ sure that the page is loaded, but you might be able to get a good guess. See updated answer above.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to check that there's nothing remaining in the event queue to be executed?

Comment: Most of the time the possibilities of web development are pretty much endless, but then there are a few instances like these where things are 'impossible'. Thanks for trying, this is the best answer so far.

Comment: Great response! While it is certainly possible to track this by applying careful discipline during development, there is truly no definitive way that the browser could determine this. This really comes down to the halting problem, which Turing has famously proven to be undecidable.

Answer (score 4):

The:

```
window.onload
```

event will fire at this point.

Comment: Yes, though strictly speaking it's the "load" event, and "onload" is the name of the property on the "window" object for the event handler :-)

Comment: Will this handle, AJAX, Flash and Silverlight?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - it won't handle AJAX since AJAX content is typically loaded "after" the page has loaded - you'd need to formally wait forever since the browser has no way of knowing whether or not more content will be loaded with AJAX. It will wait until flash etc. content has loaded, but won't wait for them to do whatever they are going to do (which might be loading more content!).

Comment: Thanks. I need a complete solution, even for AJAX.

Comment: I don't think any such solution can exist. You'd need to tell the code what your AJAX was likely to load and when it was likely to load. For instance, if at "normal" page load you set a timer to load more content via AJAX 10 minutes later, you can't expect a generic method to be able to tell that will happen without it being deeply integrated with your site. Happy if someone else can show me how that would be done in a generic way, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onLoad = function(){
    //Stuff to do when page has loaded.
}
```

or

```
<body onLoad="functionCall()">
```

Comment: Will this handle, AJAX, Flash and Silverlight?

Answer (score 3):

Basically ADW and Keith answer the question, but I would suggest not to use window.onload but:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", myfunction, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onload", myfunction);
}

function myfunction() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Will this handle, AJAX, Flash and Silverlight?

Comment: what do you mean by ajax? this is exactly the same event as `window.onload`. as ajax can be called long after the page is loaded (and it's async by nature) "loading" of an ajax request is not part of the onload event. if you execute an ajax request already while the page is loading you have to add one listener to the window.load event and one to the ajax complete event... set a global flag in both listeners and check if the other listener was already fired. if not, do nothing besides setting the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `window.onload`, `document.readyState`, and callbacks for AJAX requests, you should be able to do what you want. Simply make sure the window has loaded, the DOM is ready for manipulation, and keep track of AJAX requests.

For AJAX in particular, depending on how many requests you make: Increment a variable each time you make a request, and when the variable `===` the total amount of requests, fire a function. If you don't happen to know the amount of AJAX requests, but know which one would be last, simply have a callback function fire when it finishes.

When all is set and true, fire a final function to do what you want, knowing everything should be loaded.

In regards to Flash and Silverlight applications (not sure if `window.onload` or `document.ready` keeps track of those), you could also record the amount of data loaded withing the application, and when the loaded data `===` the total data, have the application fire a function or increment a variable to the page.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var time = window.setInterval(function() {
     if(document.readyState == "interactive") { 
         increment(); 
         window.clearInterval(time);
     }
    }, 250);
}

var total = 10, current = 0;
var increment = function() {
    current += 1;
    if(current === total) { weAreDone(); }    
}

function weAreDone() {
    // Everything should be done!
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the page, so I'm not sure if I can add callbacks to AJAX and other plugins. I like the sound of recording the amount of data for a given page and then measuring it. Is there a JavaScript functions for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the non intrusive js function I scripted, using events on load. In this case, I fire events on js script load as this is my js autoloader function, but you can just add event on other items using the same principle. Provided this script looks after js scripts loaded in a dedicated *div* tag.

```
function scriptLoaded(e) {
    var oLoadedScript = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert ('loaded : ' + oLoadedScript.src);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Import js lib and fire function ControlData on events
 * @param js_librairies
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
function init(){

    // lib import
    // Locate js in the div
    var myscript_location = document.getElementById('js_script_goes_here');


    // DEBUG
    if (undefined == myscript_location)
            alert('div not found');
        else
            alert('found div : ' + myscript_location);

 // to prevent js script from catching in dev mode
    var force_js_reload = "?version=1" ;

    for (var i=0; i < js_librairies.length ; ++i) {
        var my_script = document.createElement('script');
        my_script.defer = false;
        my_script.src = relative_path + js_librairies[i] + force_js_reload ;
        my_script.type = 'text/javascript';
        // DEBUG
        my_script.onload = scriptLoaded;

        myscript_location.appendChild(my_script);

    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Start non intrusive js
 * @param func
 */
function addLoadEvent(func) {
      var oldonload = window.onload;
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
      } else {
        window.onload = function() {
          if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
          }
          func();
        };
      }
}


//ONLOAD
addLoadEvent(init);
```

Comment: So which part of this is the non-intrusive part? I see functions in global namespace, `alert()`'s, it even overwrites any `window.onload` handlers other code may have set...

Comment: @Jani: alert was just for debug and explanation purposes. You can move this, adding a div and append it with a textnode msg, or just comment the callback line (that's why it's just commented above as "DEBUG").

Answer (score -1):

```
function r(f){/in/(document.readyState)?setTimeout(r,9,f):f()}
```

Courtesy: [Smallest DOMReady code, ever - Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever)

Update: And for IE

```
function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}
```

P.S: `window.onload` is a very different thing

Comment: The "regexp is a function" trick doesn't work in IE, unfortunately.

Comment: Will this handle, AJAX, Flash and Silverlight? IE not so important to me.

Comment: This is an onDomReady implementation. onDomReady fires as soon as HTML Tag soup of the page is fully downloaded and parsed by the browser. It doesn't care about images, css files or javascript files that are embedded on the page, so this is not what the poster asked at all. And no, it will not handle AJAX, Flash and Silverlight. There's no way to handle those at all. Even Onload event will not handle them correctly, unless you add custom events into your flash/silverlight code.

Comment: @ Ilya Volodin: I am not a visionary. I have not seen anything about Flash, Ajax or Silverlight until 17 hours ago. The question was edited. I do hope that you have downvoted the `onload` also

Comment: @naveen onload is much closer to what he as asking even before he edited a question. onDomReady will fire as soon as HTML of the page id downloaded and parsed, which doesn't constitute complete loading of the page. onload, however, will wait till all resources on the page will be downloaded, like images, css files and javascripts. It will even wait till the flash and silverlight files will be downloaded, but will not wait until they will be executed, that's not possible without custom code inside flash or silverlight. Same goes for Ajax.