# Unable to wait in page when partial page is getting loaded due to Ajax

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have some controls in html's section tag and those controls load when `ajax` request completed. Now there is a scenario where `ajax` is loaded but controls are not appearing on the page and I want to stop code execution till all controls are loaded and visible on the page.

How to identify that all controls are loaded on the page.

I don't want to use the following solutions:

1) Explicit wait in code (because I don't know when controls are loaded).

2) I don't want to use `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(id)));` (because if the particular control is not present on the page then it will wait indefinitely)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have used document.readystate but it is coming 'complete' but controls are not loaded on page because of ajax request is not completed.

Comment: Use `Google` to get more info about what is `ExplicitWait` and how `ExpectedConditions` + `WebdriverWait` works... Also provide more info, like `HTML`, programming language you use (add appropriate tag), piece of your code

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Create a class called ExtensionMethods
2. Add the following method to this class

   public static void WaitForPageToLoad(this IWebDriver driver)
   {
       TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

   ```
   IJavaScriptExecutor javascript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
   if (javascript == null)
       throw new ArgumentException("driver", "Driver must support javascript execution");

   wait.Until((d) =>
   {
       try
       {
           string readyState = javascript.ExecuteScript(
           "if (document.readyState) return document.readyState;").ToString();
           return readyState.ToLower() == "complete";
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException e)
       {
           //Window is no longer available
           return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to get browser");
       }
       catch (WebDriverException e)
       {
           //Browser is no longer available
           return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to connect");
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

   }

*This code will wait until all JavaScript is loaded.*

3. Use this method before you interact with the elements on the page

Comment: This code only waits until all static resources are loaded from the server (initiated by the url/html, but not JS), and not until all JS finishes background requests.

Comment: @skandigraun You're wrong and you should consider to remove the downvotes.

Comment: The [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) talks only about resources, not extra requests after firing the `load` event.[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190762/is-there-a-definitive-javascript-not-jquery-method-for-checking-whether-or-not) question might be also useful. The suggested solution actually is just a "busy sleep", selenium does not return nor allows interaction with the page until the page is loaded.Jquery has an easy feature to count/check ajax requests, or overriding XMLHttpRequest.readyState events could be also a solution.